# How can export logs from heroku rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, logging

I have a ruby on rails app on heroku. I need server logs with apache format: https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/log-file-analyser/user-guide/general/#importing-log-files. I need logs on last 30 days.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging - have you considered these links?

Comment: I need the user agent details, in heroku logs not appear.

Comment: A Ruby on Rails application isn't an Apache webserver. If you want your log files in the Apache instead of the default Rails format then you need to write them in the Apache format in the first place. How does your Rails logger configuration look like?

Comment: I use default config for gem lograge